# Android Zimage Kernel Can Be Unpacked?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-source, kernel-module, android-kernel

Hy Guys ..
I'm making a custom kernel project for my device, the project is almost done, but I'm having constraints about the camera, and in the kernel source there are no suitable drivers for my phone,

my last choice is just to unpack zimage stock .. can it be unpacked or not?

My Devices:

- Smartfren Andromax Ec C46B2H
- Qualcomm Snapdragon 410 Msm8916

Comment: It can indeed be unpacked.  There are writeups online, though they may make invalid assumptions about the compression used.  But unpacking will not give you either driver source or driver code you can readily link into a different kernel - unpacking is only the very very first step of the long journey in analyzing a binary kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but **not much**.

Similar to what Chris pointed out, the zImage is a binary blob which is self extracting when run by the cpu on system bootup.

So you can manually look into the initial uncompression code and do it yourself to get an uncompressed kernel binary also known as: **uImage**

Thats it. You cannot unpack it any further without counting disassembly.